# How to display Admob interstitial every time a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I would like to know how to display a Admob interstitial ad every time a button is pressed. I have managed to display a interstitial ad, but only on the first time the button is pressed. Here is my code:

```
 package hamza.gforx.com.guforx;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;



   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

     // set the ad unit ID
     mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);


      mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
         }

         @Override
         public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
             super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
         }

         @Override
         public void onAdLeftApplication() {
             super.onAdLeftApplication();
         }

         @Override
         public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
         }

         public void onAdLoaded() {
             if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
             }
          }
      });
  }



    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
     if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Bdisplay) ;
    {
        Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

   }


      public void onButton1(View v1) {
          if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
              mInterstitialAd.show();
          }
          if (v1.getId() == R.id.Button1) ;
           {
            Intent o =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page.class);
            startActivity(o);
           }

       }


   public void onButton2(View v2) {
    if (v2.getId() == R.id.Button2) ;
    {
        Intent q =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page2.class);
        startActivity(q);
    }
     if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
         mInterstitialAd.show();
    }

  }

}
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load loadIntersitialAd whenever you close you Ad for next display so call `loadIntersitialAd()` inside `onAdClosed()` method.

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        loadIntersitialAd();
     }

     @Override
     public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onAdLeftApplication() {

     }

     @Override
     public void onAdOpened() {

     }

     public void onAdLoaded() {

     }
  });

private void loadIntersitialAd(){

    AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the to load the Ad everytime (`mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest)`).

It is also possible that the Ad is not loaded yet when you hit the button, so it is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the ad every time after it is displayed. In order to allow it enough time to load before trying to show it, it is advisable to re-load (not show) the ad in the onAdClosed() callback.